# I m getting error 'unresolved import keras.layers.experimental' in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, keras

I m getting error 'unresolved import keras.layers.experimental' in visual studio

my python import list is like this

```
import sys
import math
import pandas_datareader as web
import numpy as np
import pandas.testing as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

i think problem is becouse windows cant using these libs but im not sure

Comment: Can you try to import a class directly, e.g. `from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Normalization`?

Comment: Is that the entire error output?

Comment: @flaxel it says unresolved import again

Comment: yes AMC its the entire error code

Comment: Maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26813) can help you?

Comment: thank you i m looking to it